# Replacing the first row of one matrix with a row of another matrix and then proceeding

Tags: list-manipulation

I have

```
pnew[i_] := For[tab[[1]] = tabn[[i]]; j = 2, 
               j <= 6, j++, 
               tab = ReplacePart[tab, j -> (1 + al) x tab[[j - 1]] + sigma x epsilon[[j - 1]]*tab[[j - 1]]]]
```

where tab is a 5x5 matrix of zeros,

```
epsilon={{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, 
         {4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5, 5, 5}}
```

and

```
tabn={{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}}
```

al and sigma are constants: `al = 0.5;` `sigma = 0.1;`

The question is that I want to find a tab matrix each time by having the first row replaced by one of the rows of tabn. In this example, I would get the tab matrix 3 times and I want one big matrix with all 3 realizations of tab.

I have tried `tab /@ pnew[1]` and then evaluated tab...but this gives me only one (the first) realization of tab. 
I have tried `tab # &/@[pnew[i],{i,1,3}]` but it doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `x` ? ...

Comment: I am sorry I meant x to be the multiplication sign

Comment: well, not in Mathematica

Answer (score 2):

Initializing the `tab` matrix

```
tab = ConstantArray[0, {5, 5}];
```

Defining the rules for second row onwards

```
rule[j_] := j -> (1 + al) * tab[[j - 1]] + sigma*epsilon[[j - 1]]*tab[[j - 1]]
```

`bigMat` stores the full set of results

```
bigMat = Table[
              tab = ReplacePart[tab, {1 -> tabn[[i]]}];
              res[i] = Last@Table[
                                 tab = ReplacePart[tab, {rule[j]}], {j, 2, 6}
                                 ],{i, 1, 3}
              ]
```

The individual matrices are stored in `res[i]`

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. I would try your suggestion.